# Cannot execute ansible playbook via docker container

Tags: jenkins, docker

Im executing a pipeline on jenkins that is inside a docker container. This pipeline calls another docker-compose file that executes an ansible playbook. The service  that executes the playbook is called agent, and is defined as follows:

```
agent:
  image: pjestrada/ansible
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    PROBE_HOST: "db"
    PROBE_PORT: "3306"
  command: ["probe.yml"]
```

this is the images it uses:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER Pablo Estrada <pjestradac@gmail.com>

# Prevent dpkg errors
ENV TERM=x-term-256color


RUN sed -i "s/http:\/\/archive./http:\/\/nz.archive./g" /etc/apt/sources.list


#Install ansible

RUN apt-get update -qy && \
    apt-get install -qy software-properties-common && \
    apt-add-repository -y ppa:ansible/ansible && \
    apt-get update -qy && \
    apt-get install -qy ansible

# Copy baked in playbooks

COPY ansible /ansible

# Add voulme for Ansible Playbooks
Volume /ansible
WORKDIR /ansible
RUN chmod +x /
#Entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["ansible-playbook"]
CMD ["site.yml"]
```

My local machine is Ubuntu 16.04, and when I run `docker-compose up agent` the plabook is executed successfully. However when Im inside the jenkins container im getting this error on the same command call.

```
Attaching to todobackend9dev_agent_1
[36magent_1 | [0mERROR! the playbook: site.yml does not appear to be a file
```

This are the images and compose files for my jenkins container:

```
FROM jenkins:1.642.1
MAINTAINER Pablo Estrada <pjestradac@gmail.com>

# Suppress apt installation warnings
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Change to root user
USER root

# Used to set the docker group ID
# Set to 497 by default, which is the group ID used by AWS Linux ECS Instance
ARG DOCKER_GID=497

# Create Docker Group with GID
# Set default value of 497 if DOCKER_GID set to blank string by Docker Compose
RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID:-497} docker

# Used to control Docker and Docker Compose versions installed
# NOTE: As of February 2016, AWS Linux ECS only supports Docker 1.9.1
ARG DOCKER_ENGINE=1.10.2
ARG DOCKER_COMPOSE=1.6.2

# Install base packages
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install apt-transport-https curl python-dev python-setuptools gcc make libssl-dev -y && \
    easy_install pip

# Install Docker Engine
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D && \
    echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get purge lxc-docker* -y && \
    apt-get install docker-engine=${DOCKER_ENGINE:-1.10.2}-0~trusty -y && \
    usermod -aG docker jenkins && \
    usermod -aG users jenkins

# Install Docker Compose
RUN pip install docker-compose==${DOCKER_COMPOSE:-1.6.2} && \
    pip install ansible boto boto3

# Change to jenkins user
USER jenkins


# Add Jenkins plugins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
```

Compose File:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
    external: true

services:
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        DOCKER_GID: ${DOCKER_GID}
        DOCKER_ENGINE: ${DOCKER_ENGINE}
        DOCKER_COMPOSE: ${DOCKER_COMPOSE}
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

I put a volume in order to access docker socket from my jenkins container. However, for some reason Im not being able to access the site.yml file I need for the playbook even though outside the container the file is available.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: I think you'll need to show more of how Jenkins is running your compose. When you run it by hand, your compose should be calling probe.yml, not site.yml.

Comment: It sounds like a docker in docker scenario.You have a agent running in docker controlling the docker in host. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

How sure are you about that volume mount point and your paths?

```
- jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
```

Have you tried debug via echo?  If it can't find the site.yml then paths are the most likely cause.   You can use jenkins replay on a job to iterate quickly and modify parts of the jenkins code.  That will let you run things like

```
sh "pwd; ls -la"
```

I recommend adding the equivalent within your docker container so you can check the paths.   My guess is that the workspace isn't where you think it is and you'll want to run docker with:

```
-v${env.WORKSPACE}:jenkins-workspace
```

and then within the container:

```
pushd /jenkins-worspace
```